# Best practices to lock entities/rows in data source with EJB

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jakarta-ee, ejb

So the problem. I need some mechanism to block entities in data source. For example if someone open some article in writing mode then others can't open this article in writing mode, but only in reading mode.

I see only two methods:

1. in table create some column (ex:isBlocked) and marked it as blocked
2. use EJB singleton and keep in array opened articles id.

What is better? What are the other ways to solve such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first option, downside is that if someone opens the article in edit mode and closes the browser without releasing it, that article will stay locked. You could add another column, like `lockTime` and calculate some timeout based on it, after which the article will become unlocked again.

Second option has the same downside as first, plus it wouldn't be that easy in a clustered environment (you would have to synchronize singletons across different servers in a cluster).

In JPA you also have *optimistic locking* (using `@Version`) and *pesimistic locking* (using `entityManager.lock()`), see [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_2_0_concurrency_and) or [this](http://www.developer.com/java/manage-concurrent-access-to-jpa-entity-with-locking.html) for examples, so maybe that can help you also.